# How can I call this R function written by someone else?

Tags: r

I am starting with R and came across this function written by someone, on the internet. The link is this

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fawda123/5086859/raw/17fd6d2adec4dbcf5ce750cbd1f3e0f4be9d8b19/nnet_plot_fun.r
```

Now, if I want to download this file and then call the method, where should I download and store this file? How can I make a call to this method?

Comment: Try `library(devtools); source_gist(5086859)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# just run this line your first time to install the package
# install.packages( "downloader" )

# the downloader package makes it easy to pull code from github
library(downloader)
source_url( "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fawda123/5086859/raw/17fd6d2adec4dbcf5ce750cbd1f3e0f4be9d8b19/nnet_plot_fun.r" , prompt = FALSE )

# there you have it
plot.nnet
```

Answer (score 5):

Or, Try

```
# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
source_gist(5086859)
plot.nnet
```